# Shortest Process Next Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: operating-system

I am wondering which answer is correct?For answer 1, when P5 is finish executing, then we compared about P3,P6 and P4 ,if we compare them according to the arrival time then P3 will execute first. So,my question is about do we need to follow the arrival time? Which answer is correct? Thanks.
[This is the question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7o2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is correct.

A case could be made that both are correct, but the first is "more correct."  The tiebreaker for this scheduling algorithm should be the arrival time.  Your goal is to minimize the process wait time, and it makes more sense to first run the process that has been waiting longer.

Algorithms like this will often use a priority queue, which would sort the elements from shortest burst time to longest burst time.  Queues use FIFO (first in, first out), which means if there are two elements with the same burst time, the one that was added first would be selected first.